# Redshift equivalent of NLS_DATE_FORMAT

Tags: amazon-redshift

What is redshift equivalent of NLS_DATE_FORMAT ?

For example , I want to set date format to below format

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT='YYYYMMDDHH24MISS';
```

Answer (score 1):

Redshift does not have such a configuration option. The only thing you can control is the `datestyle`: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_SET.html

Literals follow this style: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_Date_and_time_literals.html

Answer (score 1):

you can manipulate the timestamp format to be like that, then update the value you have like

```
update table  set timestamp = cast(to_char(timestamp, 'YYYYMMDDHHMMSS') as bigint)
```

so '2016-12-31 02:43:23' will be 20161231024323